# How can i set a drawable in a CircleImageView (hdodenhof/CircleImageView)?

Tags: android, drawable

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

   profilephoto.setImageDrawable(
       getResources().getDrawable(
           R.drawable.profile, 
           getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
} 
else {       
   profilephoto.setImageDrawable(
       getResources().getDrawable(
           R.drawable.profile));
}
```

I want to set an image into a circleImageView dynamically. I have used `setImageDrawable`, but the `CircleImageView` does not display any image.

Comment: Your approach looks correct. Is `R.drawable.profile` a `BitmapDrawable` or another type of `Drawable`? Is there any output to LogCat? Does it work if you replace `CircleImageView` with a plain `ImageView`? On a more general note, you might be able to use `setImageResource(R.drawable.profile)` if there's no specific requirement for `setImageDrawable` in your project.

Comment: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/issues/129

Answer (score 3):

1. add dependencies library in your gradle file

   ```
   compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
   ```
2. XML file

   ```
   < de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/profile_image"
           android:layout_width="96dp"
           android:layout_height="96dp"
           app:civ_border_width="2dp"
           app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
   ```
3. Activity class

   ```
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
   imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sa));
   ```

Comment: i created the circle imageview dynamically:                          
CircleImageView profilephoto = newCircleImageView(getApplicationContext());  when i use the method setImageBitmap it works correctly but when i use SetImageDrawable it does not display the drawable.

Answer (score 0):

add this source code: `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`.

change code:

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

To:

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```